# mySQL custom sort order ORDER BY FIELD() issues

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to sort the resutls of a `SELECT` statement using a custom order like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(id,4,5,6) LIMIT 6
```

I was expecting to have returned rows with ids: `4,5,6,1,2,3` but instead I'm getting `1,2,3,7,8,9`. What am I doing wrong?

**As a side note:** Prior to running this query, I'm pulling this sort order from the database using a different `SELECT` with a `GROUP_CONCAT` function like so:

```
SELECT group_concat(clickID ORDER BY count DESC separator ',') from table2 WHERE searchphrase='$searchphrase'
```

This results in the `4,5,6` which is then used in the main query. Is there a faster way to write this all in one statement?

Comment: you say you're doing a group_cocnat, so `id` is probably a string, and you're comparing it against integers...

Comment: Sorry the`GROUP_CONCAT` is done prior to this query and returns '4,5,6'. id is a `BIGINT`

Comment: Then there's your problem. `FIELD(id, '4,5,6')` is basically `id = '4,5,6'`. the first argument in field() is tested for equality against each subsequent argument. your csv string is a single monolithic value. You probably want `find_in_set()` instead.

Comment: Are you joining with that `GROUP_CONCAT`, or are you interpolating the result into the new query? Instead of doing two queries, you should be able to do a `JOIN` that returns whether `id` is in the list returned by the other query, and order by that.

Comment: Thanks sorry for the confusion. I've added a bit more detail now. @Barmar - sounds interesting but slightly out of my league unfortunately!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it this way

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 ORDER BY FIELD(id, 4,5,6) > 0 DESC, id
  LIMIT 6
```

Output:

```
| ID |
|----|
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/636b4/3)** demo

Comment: It's because `FIELD()` returns non-zero index if `id` is in set of values and zero otherwise.

Comment: See ``documentation`` on FIELD() for more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of the `FIELD` function. That will only make things slow.

You just need to properly use the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY id IN (4,5,6) DESC, id
LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Wow, I like this. What is the point in `FIELD()` if `IN()` does the job?

Comment: There is none. As I mentioned, it will make things run unnecessarily slow.

Answer (score 1):

here's how to do it all in one query

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON t1.id = t2.clickID AND t2.searchphrase='$searchphrase'
ORDER BY t2.clickID IS NULL ASC, t1.id ASC
```

When the `LEFT JOIN` finds no match, it sets the fields in `t2` to NULL in the returned row. This orders by this nullness.